# How do I manually launch a release?

Tags: tfs

We've got a project with a test, dev and production release. The test and production releases are set to manual. I want to manually run the release, but don't know how to do that unless I edit the release, change the environment variables from "No automated deployment" to either "After release creation" or "After successful deployment on another environment", then run the build. Then change it all back again. The build makes all of the artifacts available, for all of the releases.

But I figure there must be a way of running the manually release, manually. I just can't find how nor where to do that in TFS's web interface.  How do I do this? (Please forgive me if I've stated something wrong. Hopefully, I've made myself clear.)

We're using TFS 2015, on-premise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create a release, open it up. The release has a "Deploy" button. Clicking that will show you a list of the available environments, and you can choose one to deploy.

I don't have an instance of TFS 2015 readily available otherwise I'd post a screenshot. Here's a screenshot showing the general location of the Deploy button from Microsoft's documentation: 
[image: Release 2015.2]

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I consider this to be the answer. I didn't know how to get there, you've shown me. I've clicked on the Deploy button. I see the Prod environment that I want to deploy. It's grayed out, so I can't run it. Makes me think I'll still have to edit it to allow for me to run it. Either that or perhaps there's some permissions I don't have which won't let me manually run a release that's marked as no automated deployment. But your answer does satisfy my question. Thanks again.